# Send Ajax request using jquery in Rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I want to send an ajax request using Jquery in Rails for. I have looked up for solutions in stackoverflow and here is what i am up to.

```html
<%= f.select :id, options_from_collection_for_select(@rtypes, "id", 
              "typeName"), {include_blank: true },                    
              {'data-rtypes': @rtypes.to_json } %>
```

And my Javascript

```html
$(function () {
   // specify id or class for your select tag   
   $('select').on('change', function () {
  var rtype = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
    url: "/RequestTypes/show_sub_types/"+rtype,
    type: "GET",
  })
   });
});
```

and i have routes defined

```html
 get "/show_sub_types/:id" => "request_types#show_sub_types"
```

The problem is that i get 404 error

```html
GET http://localhost:3000/RequestTypes/show_sub_types/1 404 (Not Found)
```

Here is my show_sub_type method

```html
def show_sub_types
  @rtype = params[:id];
   @stypes = RequestSubType.where("request_type_id_id=?", @rtype).all
  respond_to do |format|
    ... some code here
  end
 end
```

I do not know how to work with respond_to, so i just leaved it as it

Comment: You can also try `match 'RequestTypes/show_sub_types/:id' => 'request_types#show_sub_types', :via => :get`. If `show_sub_types` is the method in `request_types` controller

Comment: Can you post code of action 'show_sub_types' of controller 'RequestType' controllers?

Answer (score 0):

Change route to

```
get "/RequestTypes/show_sub_types/:id" => "request_types#show_sub_types"
```

Comment: @Sergay Gorlanov, now i have internal error 500. Does it meant that my request is being sent?

Comment: may be u problem in request_types#show_sub_types.
Show logs

Comment: You have wrong where condition. Follow http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#array-conditions